# Validating JWT token and reading claims (ASP NET)

Tags: asp.net, authentication, jwt, authorization

So I'm trying to validate a token in a ASP NET core project. In my startup.cs i got the following code.

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    //ValidateAudience = true,
                    //ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                    RoleClaimType ="groups",
                    ValidateAudience = false, // `aud` claim
                    ValidateLifetime = false, // `exp`, `nbf` claims
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false, // signature
                    SignatureValidator = (token, parameters) => new JwtSecurityToken(token)
                };

                options.Events.OnTokenValidated =  context =>
                {
                    if (context.SecurityToken is JwtSecurityToken accessToken)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("=====> TOKEN EXISTS <=====");
                        var roles = accessToken.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "groups").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
                        foreach (var r in roles)
                            Console.WriteLine(r);
                    }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
```

But every time I make a request from postman with a token it fails and the stacktrace gives the following output.

```
{"EventId":13,"LogLevel":"Error","Category":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel","Message":"Connection id \u00220HMH7MN2T2OMN\u0022, Request id \u00220HMH7MN2T2OMN:00000002\u0022: An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.","Exception":"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at AdministrationService.Server.Startup.\u003C\u003Ec.\u003CConfigureServices\u003Eb__4_0(JwtBearerOptions options) in /src/Aftermarket.Server.DbApi/Server/Startup.cs:line 61
```

Line 61 one is:

```
options.Events.OnTokenValidated =  context =>
```

meaning thenOnTokenValidated returns null.

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2):

[According to docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbeareroptions.events?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

> JwtBearerOptions.Events { get; set; }
>
> The object provided by the application to process events raised by the bearer
> authentication handler. The application may implement the interface
> fully, or it may create an instance of JwtBearerEvents and assign
> delegates only to the events it wants to process.

So You have to create JwtBearerEvents object first

```cs
JwtBearerEvents events= new JwtBearerEvents();
events.OnTokenValidated = context =>
{
    (...)
};
options.Events= events;
```

Comment: ok im gonna try this.